# How to use just one DialogueFactory for different Dialogs in Rivr VoiceXML

Tags: voicexml, rivr

I am using VoiceXmlDialogueFactory to create some Dialogue's. I wonder how I can check which is the class name configured in the Dialog (in web.xml) so I don't have to create a DialogueFactory class for every Dialog and I can just if/then in the create method. I've checked that method:

```
public VoiceXmlDialogue create(DialogueInitializationInfo<VoiceXmlInputTurn, VoiceXmlOutputTurn, VoiceXmlDialogueContext> initializationInfo) throws DialogueFactoryException {
```

But didn't find where to get the com.nuecho.rivr.voicexml.dialogue.class parameter. A specific parameter I can read some other way may do the trick too.

thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want a single `DialogueFactory` class that can creates different dialogues (of different `VoiceXmlDialogue` classes) based on some external data. That's the purpose of the `DialogueFactory`, really.

The most straightforward way to do that is to use something in the initial HTTP  request (like the parameter or the path) to determine what dialogue is to be built. You can get the HttpServletRequest by casting the `initializationInfo` parameter of the `DialgueFactory.create()` into a `WebDialogueInitializationInfo`.  In this object, you will find additional properties that you can use to perform the required logic. You can even access the servlet context.

So, using a query parameter, you can create the right kind of dialog.
http://server.exemple.com/application/dialogue?type=abc

```
public class DialogueFactory implements VoiceXmlDialogueFactory {

    @Override
    public VoiceXmlDialogue create(
            DialogueInitializationInfo<VoiceXmlInputTurn, VoiceXmlOutputTurn, VoiceXmlDialogueContext> initializationInfo)
            throws DialogueFactoryException {

        if (!(initializationInfo instanceof WebDialogueInitializationInfo))
            throw new DialogueFactoryException("Can only work in web mode.");

        WebDialogueInitializationInfo<?, ?, ?> webInitializationInfo = 
            (WebDialogueInitializationInfo<?, ?, ?>) initializationInfo;

        String dialogueType = webInitializationInfo.getHttpServletRequest().getParameter("type");

        // Then use dialogueType to build the right kind of Dialogue.
    }
}
```

You can also use the path info: 
http://server.exemple.com/application/dialogue/abc

See [this cookbook entry](https://github.com/nuecho/rivr-cookbook/wiki/Spring-framework-integration) for something similar.

Comment: Thanks. I guess this also applies to subdialogs so I can include this parameters in the vxmlSubDialogURL parameter when doing new SubdialogueCall("invoke-subdialogue", vxmlSubDialogURL);